# Seongcheol's parinirvana gatha

Tags: zen, bodhisattva-vows, final-nirvana

[Seongcheol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seongcheol)'s parinirvana gatha reads:

> Deceiving people all my life, my sins outweigh Mount Sumeru.
>
> Falling into hell alive, my grief divides into ten thousand pieces.
>
> Spouting forth a red wheel,
>
> It hangs on the blue mountain.

Has anyone written about what this means? I see that Seongcheol had this explanation

> I've lived my entire life as a practitioner, and people have always
>   asked me for something. Everyone is already a Buddha, but they do not
>   try to realize that fact and only look towards me. So, in a way, you
>   could say I've deceived people all my life. I've failed to get this
>   message across to everyone so I'm suffering in a kind of hell.

But I wonder if it is definitive?

You read people who think it's an admission that he's wasted his "entire life", whereas I thought it could be a statement about "saving all sentient beings".

Comment: gah i didn't see his explanation in that article, but worth IMHO keeping the question for elaboration...

Comment: You might want to edit the question content to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of this is as follows;

***Illusion is impure, but a water wave is beyond purity and impurity;***

***May I be reborn in a hell to purify it and save the living beings there.***

Comment: not a bad answer